# Colors and Boundaries with VISIFire Charts

Tags: .net, silverlight, custom-controls

Does anyone here use VisiFire?

I have some questions about the VisiFire Charts.

The charts come with preset themes.  What if I want to have a specific color combination because the client requires certain specific colors according to their rules?  How to I override the themes and use specific colors in the charts?

A line chart that shows values that range from 4.0 to 6.0 will automatically have an upper limit of about 6.0.  What about an automatic lower limit?  Automatically the lower limit is set to zero instead of 4.0.  How does one override that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has been answered in the following posts.

http://www.visifire.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=2800

http://www.visifire.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=2801